Create 2 variables (last URL and current URL) => at on click function in react
I need help. I create a Memory App with react, my problem is i dont know how to do it. Can you help me to do 2 Variables that know my last URL (if i had clicked on a img) and my current URL (also if i had clicked on the second img)
It would be amazing if you could hepl me!
  const [lastUrl, setLastUrl] = useState('');
  const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState('');

  const handleClick = () => {
  setLastUrl(currentUrl);
  setCurrentUrl(window.location.href);
}


What is the purpose of knowing the last URL (to go back to last URL you can call back method on window history object)
You can access current URL via window object too, so why need to create a variable for it?
